# Existence of eigenvectors of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a nonzero finite dimensional vector space and let f be a linear transformation $V$ to $V$.

Then, when does $f$ have eigenvectors?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: It has eigenvectors whenever it has eigenvalues. Existence of eigenvalues depends on the field over which $V$ is defined. Since you omitted this information from the question, not much more can be said in general.

Comment: Thank you. I understand perfectly.